# Store and Search Checkbox values in custom field

Tags: database-design, custom-fields

We have Custom fields in our Database design like below

Custom_Field

```
field_id    bigint(20)
field_name  varchar(200)    
field_label varchar(200)    
field_type  varchar(45)
```

Custom_Field_Value

```
field_id    bigint(20)
date_value  datetime
number_value    decimal(18,6)
string_value    varchar(200)
text_value  text
```

Here we can able to store single values like text box,drop down,radio button and text area. Also I can use them in search queries  easily. Now I would like to store check box values which contains multiple values and I want to search agaist them. I was planning to store it in comma separated values. Is there any way to store better than this and can be used in search

Answer (score 1):

No. Do not store it in a single comma separated value field. You will not be able to sort it and to use its values easily.
Try to use a structure like the following.

At first may be you find that 3-4 tables for this kind of thing is too much but you will have many benefits from this. In this way you can sort options very easily, change the values, activate , deactivate or delete specific options and even support many languages with a few easy changes.

Also you will be able to optimize the storage capacity using 2 different types of tables, one for checkboxes that take only and integer values and one for mixed values (checkbox_option_int and checkbox_option_text respectively).

e.g. In such a way it's very easy to add a checkbox_id to a question_id and select all the possible options without redundant data in your database.

**checkbox_type**

```
id  type
1   int
2   text
```

**checkbox**

```
id  checkbox_type_id
1   1
2   1
3   2
```

**checkbox_option_int**

```
id  checkbox_id value   label   rank    active
1   1           1       A       1       yes
2   1           2       B       2       yes
3   1           5       C       4       no
4   1           8       D       3       yes
5   2           1       AA      1       yes
6   2           2       BB      2       yes
```

**checkbox_option_text**

```
id  checkbox_id value       label       rank    active
1   3           yes         Yes         1       yes
2   3           no          No          2       yes
3   3           perhaps     Perhaps     3       no
```

**EDIT:**

You can save the answers like this:

e.g.

**answer**

```
id  question_id
1   1
2   2
```

**answer_checkbox**

```
id  answer_id   checkbox_id
1   1           1
2   2           3
```

(Only checkbox with value 2 => label "B" selected)

**answer_checkbox_int**

```
answser_checkbox_id checkbox_option_int_id
1                   2
```

(Only checkbox with value 1 => label "Yes" selected)

**answer_checkbox_text**

```
answser_checkbox_id checkbox_option_text_id
2                   1
```

Comment: This will help me define custom field tables. My question was about how to store the values which user selected. I think we can have separate table which will act as many-to-many relationship between checkbox and checkbox_option_text. Am I correct here ?

Comment: Yes, this is the case. If you divide the options to 2 tables you have to check on the application layer about the type of checkbox but this is relatively easy. Otherwise you can merge the 2 tables for simplicity.